# How to detect of finished the function of the web page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to create the chrome extension that close the tab when this button is pushed and this function is finished in this web site.
(I want to paste URL of this web site, but I can’t paste this site. Because this web site that to download Hentai Manga.)

This button is changing animation during is downloading in this site.
And I tried the event that is called “animationend” in javascript but I could not it.

Could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: You need a *content script* to run things and listen to events in the web page. You can use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) for coordination and exchange of data (only simple data like strings or numbers or objects/arrays of such simple data).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. You should mention what you have tried and show your code for example.